# Unable to load dynamic library 'phplpsolve55.so' undefined symbol: zif_drivername

Tags: php, debian-buster, lpsolve

I am on Debian Buster running in a LXC container.

I use a self-compilied version for php of lpsolve.

I install it using this commands from [makao/lpsolve.md](https://gist.github.com/makao/11df9dec60663dcf3e0c)

The sources I use come from this repo: [myfarms/php_lp_solve](https://github.com/myfarms/php_lp_solve)

While I was able to compile the php extension for php7.4 in the past, compiling now leads to an error. This error now appears for all php versions I tried (7.4, 8.0, 8.1).

When I enter `make` followed by `make test` I get following response:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'phplpsolve55.so' (tried: /usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/modules/phplpsolve55.so (/usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/modules/phplpsolve55.so: undefined symbol: zif_drivername), /usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/modules/phplpsolve55.so.so (/usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/modules/phplpsolve55.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to find a solution on my own, but a google search for `zif_drivername`does not give any results.

A find search for `zif_drivername`shows me 3 results which all appear in binary files:

Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei /usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/modules/phplpsolve55.so
Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei /usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/.libs/PHPmod.o
Übereinstimmungen in Binärdatei /usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/.libs/phplpsolve55.so

So my question is: Does someone know how to fix this?

**Update:**

I was able to find a workaround which leads to only a warning as far as I can see now.

When compiling the extension it uses the file `PHPmod.c`
The first lines here are:

```
#include "lpsolvecaller.h"

extern PHP_FUNCTION(drivername);

static function_entry php_phplpsolve55_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(drivername, NULL)
    { NULL, NULL, NULL }
};
```

If I replace `drivername`with `lpsolve`, then I only get the warning:
`Warning: Missing arginfo for lpsolve() in Unknown on line 0`

The final code which seems to work right now looks like the following:

```
#include "lpsolvecaller.h"

extern PHP_FUNCTION(lpsolve);

static function_entry php_phplpsolve55_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(lpsolve, NULL)
    { NULL, NULL, NULL }
};
```

Maybe someone can provide some insides on where to look at, to resolve that issue finally.

Comment: Might be a permission issue

Comment: What a permission would that be? I run all commands as root.

Comment: can you navigate to `/usr/lib/lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/modules/` and make sure that phplpsolve55 is there?

Comment: yes, the binary is there. 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root      997 Dez 19 19:55 phplpsolve55.la
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root   root   528200 Dez 19 19:55 phplpsolve55.so